# folly/Optional.h not found under ExpoModulesCore

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-core-modules

Xcode build is failing with ***ExpoModulesCore/EXExportedModule.h' file not found***. My apllication is using react-native version : 0.63.4 and expo version : 42.0.0

[image]

Comment: have you tried removing node modules ?

Comment: and again installed it?

Comment: Yes I ran following commands:

npm cache clean --force && npm cache verify && rm -rf ios/build && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm i

rm -rf Pods && pod install

facing the same isssue

Comment: hello. did you find a solution to this? I'm seeing the same thing.